# Delay event on startup of program. XCODE

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

```
-(void)playpattern {
for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
int button = myIntegers [i];
if (button==1) { 
              [yellow setVisible:NO];
}
}
```

BELOW INIT

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++)
    myIntegers [i]=(i%4)+1;



    yellowbg = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"yellowxlixk.png"];
    [yellowbg setPosition:ccp(509, 671.75)];
          yellowbg.scale = .75;
    [self addChild:yellowbg z: 1];




    [self playpattern];



}

return self;
}
```

How do I delay this action on startup?. I am very new to this, please be basic in your explanation. If i need to add anything let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use performSelector OR scheduleOnce.

1. Using scheduleOnce.

   [self scheduleOnce:@selector(playpattern) delay:3];
2. Using performSelector

   [self performSelector:@selector(playpattern) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];

Comment: Where do I put the code?

Comment: replace [self playpattern]; with any of above code..